# Scaling to "Fit All Columns on One Page" in birt

Tags: javascript, excel, printing, birt, emitter

The report I have developed contains so many columns that they do not fit into the sheet when report gets printed.

I am trying to change its scaling to "Fit All Columns on One Page".

As I understand the way to do this is to set `ExcelEmitter.PrintPagesWide` to 1 and `ExcelEmitter.PrintPagesHigh` to 0.

But it does not work for me. I have tried to put

```
this.setUserProperty("ExcelEmitter.PrintScale","95")
```

to `beforefactory` and it does work.

But when I change this line to

```
this.setUserProperty("ExcelEmitter.PrintPagesWide ","1")
this.setUserProperty("ExcelEmitter.PrintPagesHigh ","0")
```

it does not work.

What do I miss? I thought it might be that I need to switch from "Adjust to" to "Fit to" somehow, but could not find how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the excel emitter. I'm using spudsoft :

https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/wiki/

you should delete the birt default excel emitter and add the spudsoft, then use ExcelEmitter.PrintScale : If the value set greater than 0, your report will be set as Excel print scale.